# Change background color div before

Tags: jquery, css

I need change the backgrou nd color of the div "#cont-comentarios" when i click on checkbox. That will works on a loop so i need use 'this'. I've tried a lot before ask here.
Folow the code here for a better view:

```
<div id="cont-comentario" style="margin-bottom: 10px; background:#eee; padding: 10px;">
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="atualizaComentario"/> Ativo
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9pMKy/

Comment: Using `.parent` will go one step up. To go more up use `.parents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to locate your div ancestor, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('input#atualizaComentario').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').css('background-color','green');
    });
});
```

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/9pMKy/1/)

Answer (score 3):

You were close

```
$(function(){
    $('#atualizaComentario').click(function(){
        $(this).parents('div#cont-comentario').css({backgroundColor:'green'});
    });
});
```

Comment: one difference - it will apply the css to all parent div, where as @Nelson way applies to the first parent div. its your choice how to choose one over other.

Comment: really the parent div should have a class associated with it so you aren't just calling off of a basic tag.

Comment: Change to this `$(this).parents('div#cont-comentario').css({backgroundColor:'green'});` and it will be fine.